# What's the purpose of using 'of ' a preposition here?

Tags: prepositions

> A 50 year old man complains **of** sudden onset of fever with chill and rigor .

I think it might also be written by following manner -

> A 50 year old man complains sudden onset of fever with chill and rigor .

Does it change its meaning?
I am really stuck here.

Please help me find the proper use of the **'of'** preposition.
Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, it is obligatory in your example. "Of" can have many meanings, but here it is used to link "complain" to the thing that is being complained about, such as an illness as in your example.

Comment: And the reason it’s obligatory is that *complain* is an intransitive verb.